# How to create GlobalKTable in the Processor API?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Is there a `GlobalKTable` (in DSL API) equivalent in the Kafka Streams Processor API i.e. is there a way to configure state stores so that their state is global rather than sharded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Topology#addGlobalStore](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html#addGlobalStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorSupplier-) is what you are looking for.
Here's an example usage from the [KafkaStreamsTest](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreamsTest.java#L668)

Comment: I noticed that the Confluent documentation here https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#streams-concepts-globalktable states that "Only the Kafka Streams DSL has the notion of a GlobalKTable." - just wanted to make sure that it is inaccurate ?